# JasperReports field null

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, jasper-reports

I'm using JasperReports & J2EE, 
now i don't want to use any connection or a Datasource, i just want to pass some values to the report and to be printed, 
i inserted a field in the report and a textField:

```
<field name="user" class="java.lang.String"/>

<textField>
    <reportElement x="348" y="30" width="100" height="20" uuid="9593564a-6367-4a98-a0c6-19a11ac45977"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{user}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

and i'm using this code in java class:

Map parameters = new HashMap();

```
parameters.put("user", "test");
    try {
        System.out.println();
        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(path + "report1.jasper", parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());

        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jp, path + "test1.pdf");

    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but the field is always set to null, 
because i'm not using any connection, i set in the report properties "When No Data" equal to "All section, No detail".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, regarding your comment, try to declare a parameter `user`, instead of field:

```
<parameter name="user" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

Then, use the syntax `$P{user}` instead of `$F{user}` in your `textFieldExpression`:

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{user}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

`$F` is for fields (data you get from your data source). `$P` is for parameters (used as input to your report, queries, etc.)

Comment: when i try to compile the report, i get "Parameter not found: user"

Comment: oops, of course, I'll give you a more complete answer :)